# Waiting for async call

Tags: node.js

I need to get the title of HTML page and I am using [node-metainspector](https://github.com/gabceb/node-metainspector).

I have created a module:

```
var MetaInspector = require('node-metainspector');

exports.getTitle = function(url) {
  var fullUrl = "http://" + url;
  var inspector = new MetaInspector(fullUrl, {});
  var title = '';

  inspector.on('fetch', function() {
    title = inspector.title;
    console.log(title);
    return title;
  });

  inspector.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  inspector.fetch();
}
```

And use it in my express application:

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
  var url = req.body.url;
  console.log(url);
  console.log(parser.getTitle(url));
}
```

This code doesn't work correctly.  The line `console.log(parser.getTitle(url));` returns `undefined`.
I think the reason is async nature of JS. `inspector.on('fetch')` is called after getTitle() finished. But I am new with node.js and I don't know what is the good pattern to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert `getTitle` into an asynchronous function by adding a callback parameter:

```
exports.getTitle = function(url, cb) {

  // ...

  inspector.on('fetch', function() {
    title = inspector.title;
    cb(null, title);
  });

  inspector.on('error', function(error) {
    cb(error);
  });
}
```

...then call it like this:

```
foo.getTitle(src, function(err, title) {
  if (err) { /* handle error */ }
  // Handle title
});
```